# Did Sky TG24 broadcast video misattributed to be the 2016 Brussels attack?

Tags: terrorism, media

According to [AnaHera.news](http://it.anahera.news/attentanto-bruxelles-false-flag/) (in Italian), Sky TG24 broadcast videos purportedly of the airport and metro attacks in Brussels, but were actually footage of the 24 January 2011 attack in Moscow.

[The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/brussels-explosions-video-purporting-to-show-zaventem-airport-blast-was-shot-in-2011-a6945501.html) also claimed the videos were wrongly attributed.

Is that true?

Comment: there are a lot of dead-enders out there who want youtube views or social media hits and aren't above relabeling videos to suit that agenda, and some in the media aren't above wringing their hands about it and making mountains out of molehills in order to get more views and advertising revenue.

Comment: @user568458 The videos on object are reported in both websites. Did you read the articles? According to the first link the video is being broadcast by Sky TG24 (the Italian counterpart of Sky News). The Independent doesn't mention where the "fake" is being broadcast, just that it's spreading through social media.

Comment: There are apparently videos around from the Minsk metro attacks too.